# Create a simple java random number pick with in a certain range

Tags: java, random

I tried searching on here for something similar, but failed to find it, maybe using wrong keywords let me know, but here is the deal.

I am fairly new with java and wanted to make something useful myself.
My idea was to create a random number picker within a range with.
So let's say range is from 1-50, and I want 5 random number in this range, and they have to be all different.  I have worked with Random before, but not sure what I am doing wrong, here is the code I have so far, please push me in the right direction if possible.
I want to create an array or list with the number, or is there a better way to do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Randomizer {
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static int rnd(int a, int b){
        return a+rnd.nextInt(b-a+1);
    }

    public static void nPicker(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter start of range: ");
        int start = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter end of range: ");
        int end = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter amount of numbers to pick: ");
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close(); 
        rnd(start,end);
        int[] randomArrays = new int[c];

        for(int i = 0; i>randomArrays.length; i++){
            randomArrays.add();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nPicker();
    }

}
```

sorry if my code is messy. 
At the moment I can't even get the random number to be added into the array

Comment: So what's wrong? Besides the condition in your `for` loop.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I am trying to add every step a new number, later I will check if the number is in the array, but for some reason it wont let me add anything into the array, should i use a list instead?

Comment: `randomArrays.add();` - this doesn't compile. `for(int i = 0; i>randomArrays.length; i++){` - this never executes the loop (unless you pick zero numbers) because i is smaller, not greater, than the length of the array. `rnd(start,end);` - you're calling the method but you're not doing anything with the return value.

Comment: Yeah sorry wrong directions should be i<randomArrays.length;   But still not sure how can I add to the array, or should i switch to lists?

Comment: you should add an integer so the result from the method rnd, like int intIn = rnd(start,end); randomArrays.add(intIn);  in the for loop ,or something more meaningful

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I did explain to you what is wrong with comments at the code, read them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Randomizer {

static int[] randomArrays; // You need to declare the vector as an instance variable, otherwise it will disappear when the method it's done. 

static Random rnd = new Random();

static int rnd(int a, int b){
    return a+rnd.nextInt(b-a+1);
}

public static void nPicker(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter start of range: ");
    int start = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter end of range: ");
    int end = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter amount of numbers to pick: ");
    int c = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close(); 
    randomArrays = new int[c];

    for(int i = 0; i<randomArrays.length; i++){ // The condition was wrong


        int numberToAdd = rnd(start,end);

        randomArrays[i] = numberToAdd; //You are not using an ArrayList, vector has not the method add(), you have to add new element to the vector throughout its index
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Randomizer rdm = new Randomizer();

   rdm.nPicker();

   for(int number:rdm.randomArrays) {

        System.out.println(number);

   }  

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your advices and hints. In the end I think I managed to get the code how I wanted with the code below.
Tell me if you see an error in this method, or if it has a way that is not allowed in java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Randomizer {
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static int rnd(int a, int b){
        return a+rnd.nextInt(b-a+1);
    }

    public static void nPicker(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter start of range: ");
        int start = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter end of range: ");
        int end = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter amount of numbers to pick: ");
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close(); 
        List randomnumbers = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i<c; i++){
            int numb = rnd(start,end);
            if(randomnumbers.contains(numb)){
                break;
            }else{
                randomnumbers.add(numb);
            }

        }
        randomnumbers.forEach(System.out::println); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nPicker();
    }

}
```

ok in the end i changed the loops as following:

```
for(int i = 0; i<c;){
            int numb = rnd(start,end);
            while(!(randomnumbers.contains(numb))){
                randomnumbers.add(numb);
                i++;
            }
        }
        randomnumbers.forEach(System.out::println); 
    }
```

seems to work fine this way

Comment: i modified where the i++ happens, as it should only ++ when it adds a number into the list right?

Comment: never mind i see there is more problems in this code